# [Symony 4.2][WebTestCase] Provide autowiring services and api controller args

Tags: symfony, functional-testing

I'm new on Symfony functional test world and trying to test my first API controller with a lot of trouble...

I'm trying to test that endpoint :

```
    $token = $em->getRepository(Token::class)->findOneBy(['value' => $tokenValue]);

    if ($token && $this->getCurrentUser() && $token->getUser()->getId() === $this->getUser()->getId()) {
        $em->remove($token);
        $em->flush();
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
```

Problems: That controller use EntityManager, TokenInterface (not used, just for example), and a string token value.
I can provide entityManager interface with initializing it in static::$container, but can't with TokenInterface and don't know how to proceed for $tokenValue

Here's my test :

```
    $this->tokenStorage = self::$container->get('security.token_storage');
    $this->session      = self::$container->get('session'); 
    
    $this->currentUser  = $this->generateFakeEntity(User::class, $currentUserData);
    $token              = new UsernamePasswordToken($this->currentUser, null, 'api', $this->currentUser->getRoles());

    $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
    $this->session->set('_security_api', serialize($this->tokenStorage->getToken()));
    $this->session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($this->session->getName(), $this->session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);

    $this->client->request(Request::METHOD_DELETE, '/api/external/v1/fr/34pas40EasterEGGDigitemisKeyTesterCDouterCorrigerCAbdiquer2020ItIsNotABugItIsAFeature/34pas40/auth-tokens/1');

    $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame($expectedCode, $this->wrongStatusCodeError($expectedCode, self::PREFIX_SUPER_ADMIN . '/auth-tokens/', __METHOD__));
```

$tokenValue error :

> Controller "App\Api\SuperAdminApiController::removeAuthTokenAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$tokenValue" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

TokenInterface error :

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException: Cannot autowire argument $token of "App\Api\SuperAdminApiController::removeAuthTokenAction()": it references interface "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

Question: How to proceed to inject that required arguments from a functional test?

Thank you in advance for your time :)

Comment: I like how you error messages are way more readable than the code. please post code as code not as an image. enclose code with lines consisting only of triple backticks, for example. nobody likes to retype all your code to insert improvements / bug fixes for example.

Comment: I understand and I apologize, I have applied the changes

Comment: it's really weird, the webtestcase should properly initialize symfony, but there appear to be controller arguments missing / not being autowired. Also TokenInterface indeed isn't a usual service, use the TokenStorageInterface instead and use ->getToken. The $tokenValue I can't wrap my head around, since it should be part of the uri/path, right? maybe showing the function signature of your controller action gives more insight?

Comment: Thanks a lot, your questions help me to find solution. TokenStorageInterface works fine and tokenValue match with route parameters.  My team told me the controller works but it's false ! x)